# How to get Start and End time of DaylightSavingTime for UK time zone?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, nodatime

I want to get the Day Light Saving DateTime Start and End DateTime for the UK timezone.

In the UK the clocks go forward 1 hour at 1 am on the last Sunday in March, and back 1 hour at 2 am on the last Sunday in October.

This year it is from 27 Mar to 30 October.

I can get this time range by getting this data for a given year (like last Sunday in March...) and hardcode this. But Is there a better way or any C# method already there? Or any library which could give the start and end time based on just passing the time zone?
So that If I need it for the US time zone, I can get this information easily, but by again reading the Daylight saving details and writing the code for it.

Comment: NodaTime might do this - https://nodatime.org/

Comment: @stuartd any reference for the relevant code?

Comment: Use the code in the duplicate, with `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"]`

Comment: @JonSkeet is there a way to convert LocalDateTime to C# DateTime directly?

Comment: @viveknuna: Did you look in the [documentation](https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDateTime.html#methods) or try browsing the API with Intellisense before asking? I would have thought `ToDateTimeUnspecified` would be fairly easy to discover.

Comment: @JonSkeet where can I find the Key for CST? So that I can access it using `DateTimrZoneProviders.Txdb[“key”]`

Comment: @viveknuna: What do you mean by "the CST"? It's just a time zone ID. See https://nodatime.org/TimeZones for the list of IANA time zones. If you use `DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl` then it'll use the system IDs as advertised by `DateTimeInfo`.